# Recompile a .gz file in emacs' progmodes directory

Tags: elisp, byte-compilation

`c-electric-lt-gt` in `cc-cmds.el.gz` treats `>` as a closing paren only if it isn't immediately followed by another `>`. This behaviour is incorrect for C++11 and I tried to modify it by changing the order of the checks in that function.

How do I recompile this compressed file? Calling `byte-recompile-file` on `cc-cmds.el.gz` failed on the first `require` statement - `(require 'cc-defs)`. However, `cc-defs` is provided in the `cc-defs.el.gz` file present in the same directory as `cc-cmds.el.gz`. Also, simply evaluating `(require 'cc-defs)` in `ielm` works without any errors.

Comment: If you're messing with it, might as well extract from archive and byte-compile the .el file.

Comment: @abo-abo What about the dependencies though? Should I extract every one of them as well? I am trying to understand why it failed to find `'cc-defs`.

Comment: No, you can just load them.

Comment: Sorry, I seem to be missing something. Simply evaluating `(require 'cc-defs)` in my emacs session works without any trouble. I assumed this meant the required file is in the `load-path`. Is there another definition of loading which applies to byte-compilation? If not, why does the byte-compilation run into trouble?

Comment: It is possible, but unlikely that some dependencies are only required during compile time. However, the way you describe it it sounds like it's only required during compile time. So, yes, technically extracting the missing sources and recompiling them would have worked (I believe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't modify files in Emacs's directory. They'll be overwritten if you upgrade Emacs and they won't be available on other machines.

Instead, provide your own definition for the function in your init file.

```
(defun pradhan:after-load:cc-cmds ()
  (if t ; replace this by a test that checks whether the bug is present in this version of Emacs
      (defun c-electric-lt-gt …)))
(eval-after-load "cc-cmds" 'pradhan:after-load:cc-cmds)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking if you're doing something, might as well do it right.
Messing about probably in your `/usr/local/` isn't good.
Do this instead:

```
git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/emacs.git
```

1. Make your changes
2. Track your changes with git
3. Install your changes with `sudo make install`
4. Propagate your changes with `git format-patch` and `emacs-devel@gnu.org`

Comment: +1. Thanks! Will try that. But I was hoping to understand why my current attempt failed.

Comment: It could be many things, maybe lack of permissions etc. It's easier to just do it right.